# Alternating Series Approximation Theorem

Tags: calculus

[I am given an integral that needs to be approximated, but the integral looks impossible to evaluate without a u-substitution.

[image]

Comment: The indefinite integral hasn't got a simple closed form...that's why you were asked to  approximate the definite integral numerically.  Hint:  express $e^{-x^2}$ as a power series and integrate term by term.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=1+x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3+\dots$$

Solution (hover or click the box to view once you've worked it out):

> \begin{align}\int_0^ae^{-x^2}\ dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{a^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\end{align}

and finally,

> \begin{align}\left|\int_0^{1/2}e^{-x^2}\ dx-\sum_{n=0}^4\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n+1)2^{2n+1}}\right|<\frac1{5!\times11\times2^{11}}\end{align}